# Powershell: save bold text into variable

Tags: excel, powershell, import, typography

I'd like to ask you for a help how to save bold text into variable from Excel via Powershell. I'm not a full time developer, just trying to make my life easier with Powershell :)

This is what I have (it's not a lot unfortunately):

```
# Open file test.xlsx
$excel = Open-ExcelPackage -Path './test.xlsx'

# Copy content of the worsksheet 'Sheet1'
$worksheet = $excel.Workbook.Worksheets['Sheet1']

# Copy specific cell value to the variable    
$String = $worksheet.Value
$StringBold = 

# Close Excel file
Close-ExcelPackage -ExcelPackage $Excel
```

I'm able to save content of the file test.xlsx into `&worksheet` variable. In some cell might be the string 'How are you today **Marek**?' So the next step should be to save only word **Marek** into the variable `$StringBold`

Thanks a lot for any advice.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, I need to extract bold text only, nothing else. Do you know how else this could be achieved please?

Answer (score 1):

After some research this seems possible using the [`ImportExcel` Module](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel), you just need to enumerate each [cell](https://epplussoftware.com/docs/5.3/api/OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRangeBase.htm) and then access their [`.RichText` property](https://epplussoftware.com/docs/5.3/api/OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRangeBase.html#OfficeOpenXml_ExcelRangeBase_RichText). Here is an example of how you can achieve it:

```
$xlsx  = Open-ExcelPackage path\to\my.xlsx
$sheet = $xlsx.Workbook.Worksheets['mySheetName']
foreach($cell in $sheet.Cells) {
    foreach($richText in $cell.RichText) {
        if($richText.Bold) {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Address = $cell.Address
                Value   = $richText.Text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using this Sheet as an example:

[image: test]

The result with this code becomes:

```
Address Value
------- -----
A2      Marek
A3      Hello
```

Comment: This looks great @Santiago Squarzon. However, how could I save bold values into the variable? I was trying to do that, but without success :(.

The main goal is to identify bold string in xlsx, wrap it with HTML code and save/close xlsx. For example, **Marek** will be replaced with _<span style="font-weight: bold;">Marek</span>_

Comment: @MarekSanoba that should be a different question. This answer intends to answer the initial question